# Нанесение текста на готовое изображение и вывод как изображение

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, изображения

Есть готовое изображение (шаблон), и есть тест. Например *"Я занял #1 место в рейтинге"*. Надо нанести этот текст на изображение в определенном месте с определенными стилями и при этом изображение должно остаться изображением и на нем должен быть текст.

Другого варианта каким образом сделать og:image для соц сети я не передумал.

**Возможно ли сделать такое на js (jq)?** Если да, то как?

Comment: https://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/text.html

Answer (score 0):

библиотека html2canvas
вот пример кода`htmlToImage = function(className, obj) {
    var element = document.getElementById(className);
    html2canvas(element, {
      logging: false,
      profile: true,
      useCORS: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);
        obj.customImg = myImage;
    });
  };`